# how to to do the "noop but return unit" in OCaml

Tags: pattern-matching, ocaml, no-op

I want to print a list of strings after going through a pattern matching just to get into this powerful functionality.

How can I express the "do-nothing-but-return-unit" operation ?

What I mean is:

```
let print_nodes nodes =
  match nodes with
      []     -> (* here i want to noop *)
    | s :: t -> print_string s; print_nodes t
```

Comment: (I know that I can use the iter function but i was just curious)

Comment: yes, but I wrote the code on the fly so I forgot :)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can simply write `()`.

See [Variant values](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/manual010.html) in the manual: `()` is how you build the `unit` value.

Comment: Ok, just searched for it and got it! Sorry for this dumb/simple question but haven't found the () empty unit until now :/

Comment: @Jack Well, it is not used that often :) If you write in a purely functional style (without side-effects) you never have to use it at all...